# Open a SaveFileDialog using the Microsoft Project application

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I'm working on a VBA macro which generates an Excel report out of a Microsoft Project planning.

In order to save the report, I have to open a *Save File Dialog* by calling 
`GetSaveAsFilename("name", , , "Title")`, but I don't want to use the `Excel.Application` for this because I'm supposed to activate it first which doesn't make sense.

How should I call `GetSaveAsFilename` through the Microsoft Project application?

Comment: Is this VB or VBA? It sounds like you are not actually working in Excel. @JoelCoehoorn, is your edit to VBA the right tag?

Comment: @Gaffi - it is. "I'm working on a vb macro" macro == vba

Answer (score 1):

MS Project uses `FileSaveAs` instead of `GetSaveAsFilename`, which has several arguments. If you leave them blank you will just get the `SaveAs` dialog box.